# Flutter remove duplicate array by value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an array that has the same name value I just need to check if the same value comes it will delete it.

My data looks like

```
[{'name':'Rameez', 'data': [{'age': 1, 'number': 2}]}, {'name':'XYZ', 'data': [{'age': 1, 'number': 2}]}, {'name':'Rameez', 'data': [{'age': 1, 'number': 2}]}];
```

I want to show it like this no duplicate name

```
Expected output dataaa = [{'name':'Rameez', 'data': [{'age': 1, 'number': 2}]}, {'name':'XYZ', 'data': [{'age': 1, 'number': 2}]}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var list = [{'name':'Rameez', 'data': [{'age': 1, 'number': 2}]}, 
               {'name':'XYZ', 'data': [{'age': 1, 'number': 2}]},
               {'name':'Rameez', 'data': [{'age': 1, 'number': 2}]}];

   for(int i = 0;i< list.length;i++){
      for(int j = i+1;j< list.length;j++){
        if(list[i]["name"] == list[j]["name"]){
          list.removeAt(j);
        }
      }
   }

  list.forEach((item) => print(item.toString()));
```

##### Output

```
{name: Rameez, data: [{age: 1, number: 2}]}
{name: XYZ, data: [{age: 1, number: 2}]}
```